# A Linux Kernel Module for Self-Optimizing Hard Drives: Advice?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am a computer engineering student studying Linux kernel development. My 4-man team was tasked to propose a kernel development project (to be implemented in 6 weeks), and we came up with a tentative "Self-Optimizing Hard Disk Drive Linux Kernel Module". I'm not sure if that title makes sense to the pros.

We based the proposal on this [project](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~sburnett/download/borg.pdf).

The goal of the project is to minimize hard disk access times. The plan is to create a special partition where the "most commonly used" files are to be placed. An LKM will profile, analyze, plan, and redirect I/O operations to the hard disk. This LKM should primarily be able to predict and redirect all file access (on files with sizes of < 10 MB) with minimal overhead, and lessen average read/write access times to the hard disk. I believe Apple's HFS has this feature.

Can anybody suggest a starting point? I recently found a way to redirect I/O operations by intercepting system calls (by [hijacking](http://memset.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/syscall-hijacking-dynamically-obtain-syscall-table-address-kernel-2-6-x/) all the read/write ones). However, I'm not convinced that this is the best way to go. Is there a way to write a driver that redirects these read/write operations? Can we perhaps tap into the read/write cache to achieve the same effect?

Any feedback at all is appreciated.

Comment: If anybody is interested, I'm documenting some of my research and asking questions in this new [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382720/safer-alternative-to-system-call-hijacking). Feel free to post there...thanks.

Comment: I set up this new [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466083/trying-to-modify-unionfs-code-find-writeable-branch-need-help). It's about unionfs. I need some help to modify some of its code. If anybody can offer advice, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at Unionfs. You don't even need a LKM - just a some user-space daemon which would subscribe to inotify events, keep statistics and migrate files between partitions. Unionfs will combine both partitions into a single logical filesystem.

Comment: Yup, I've been looking at the code for some time now. UnionFS and AuFS look like they can do the job. However, their latest versions seem to lack the ability to delete all files in all branches instead of just whiting them out. I also need to update files in both branches when writing occurs, not just the one the the top branch. Hmmm...

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways in which such optimizations might be useful:

- accessing file `A` implies file `B` access is imminent.  Example: opening an icon file for a media file by a media player
- accessing any file in some group `G` of files means that other files in the group will be accessed shortly.  Example: `mysql` receives a `use somedb` command which implies all the file tables, indexes, etc. will be accessed.
- a program which stops reading a sequential file suggests the program has stalled or exited, so predictions of future accesses associated with that file should be abandoned.
- having multiple (yet transparent) copies of some frequently referenced files strategically sprinkled about can use the copy nearest the disk heads.  Example: uncached directories or small, frequently accessed settings files.

There are so many possibilities that I think at least 50% of an efficient solution would be a sensible, limited specification for what features you will attempt to implement and what you won't.  It might be valuable to study how Microsoft's Vista's aggressive file caching mechanism [disappointed](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/09/why-does-vista-use-all-my-memory.html).

Another problem you might encounter with a modern Linux distribution is how well the system already does much of what you plan to improve.  In fact, measuring the improvement might be a big challenge.  I suggest writing a benchmark program which opens and reads a series of files and precisely times the complete sequence.  Run it several times with your improvements enabled and disabled.  But you'll have to reboot in between for valid timing....

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I agree, especially about how Linux already has similar mechanisms. However, that part does not really matter as much as the learning experience. Oh, and if you know something about redirecting disk reads/writes, please do post. I don't think that hijacking syscalls is optimal due to the overhead, and I can't find documentation of a better way.

Comment: @rb3:  the only idea which springs to mind is a user space file system driver.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace